# Can somebody help me solve the database?

Tags: java, android, database

Hello everybody i m building an android application which has timepicker. what i want is that i want to update the database when user clicks the save button twice. Please guide me how to do that. Now my application crashes because no updation of database takes place.

TimeTable.java

```
    public class Monday extends FragmentActivity implements TimePickerFragment.TimePickerDialogListener {
    EditText et1, et2, et3;
    TextView tvm;
    LinearLayout llm;
    int fhour, fmin, thour, tmin, j;
    private int cnt = 0;
    View vi[] = new View[100];
    TimeTableDbHelper db;
    String txt,fmeridien,tmeridien,ftime,ttime;
    private static final int START_TIME_PICKER_ID = 1;
    private static final int END_TIME_PICKER_ID = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_monday);
        tvm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvm);
        llm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llm);
        db = new TimeTableDbHelper(this);

        cnt = db.check("timetableM");
        if (cnt > 0) {
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
                LinearLayout mn = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llm);
                View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_timepicker, mn, false);
                vi[i] = view;
                mn.addView(view);
                et1 = (EditText) vi[i].findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
                et1.setText(db.rd1(i,1));
                //Log.i("Monday", "Database read" + db.read(2) + db.read(3));
                et2 = (EditText) vi[i].findViewById(R.id.txtTime2);
                et2.setText(db.rd1(i,2));
                //Log.i("Monday", "Database read" + db.read(4) + db.read(5));
                et3 = (EditText) vi[i].findViewById(R.id.txtSet);
                et3.setText(db.rd1(i,3));
            }
            j = i;
        } else {
            j = 0;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_monday, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void setTime(View v) {
        LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llm);
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_timepicker, main, false);
        view.setTag(j);
        main.addView(view);
        vi[j] = view;
    }

    public void setTime2(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = TimePickerFragment.newInstance(START_TIME_PICKER_ID);
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    }

    public void setTime3(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = TimePickerFragment.newInstance(END_TIME_PICKER_ID);
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(int id, TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        Log.i("TimePicker", "Time picker set from id " + id + "!");
        if (id == START_TIME_PICKER_ID) {
            et1 = (EditText) vi[j].findViewById(R.id.txtTime);

            fmin = minute;
            if(hourOfDay <= 12) {
                fhour = hourOfDay;
                fmeridien = "AM";
            } else {
                fhour = hourOfDay-12;
                fmeridien = "PM";
            }
                ftime =fhour + ":" + fmin + fmeridien;

            et1.setText(ftime);
        } else {
            et2 = (EditText) vi[j].findViewById(R.id.txtTime2);
            tmin = minute;
            if(hourOfDay < 12) {
                thour = hourOfDay;
                tmeridien = "AM";
            } else {
                thour = hourOfDay-12;
                tmeridien = "PM";
            }
            ttime = thour + ":" + tmin +tmeridien;
            et2.setText(ttime);
        }
    }
    public void Save(View v)
    {
        int position = (int) v.getTag();
        if(position<j);
        else {
            et3 = (EditText) vi[j].findViewById(R.id.txtSet);
            txt = et3.getText().toString();
            Log.i("Position", "Value is " + position);

            db.write1(j, ftime, ttime, txt);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        int value;
        if(fmeridien=="AM") value=0;
        else value=1;
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,day);
        c.set(Calendar.AM_PM, value);
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR, fhour);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, fmin);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
        Intent i = new Intent("com.example.annu.sheduler.DisplayNotification");
        //---assign an ID of 1---
        i.putExtra("NotifID", j);
        i.putExtra("text",txt);
        PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getBaseContext(), j, i, 0);
        j++;
        //---sets the alarm to trigger---
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                c.getTimeInMillis(), displayIntent);}
    }
}
```

activity_monday.xml

```
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llm"
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context="com.example.annu.sheduler.Monday"
              android:background="#ffffa751"
              android:label="Monday">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="setTime"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:text="Create a schedule"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_timepicker.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtTime"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".30"
        android:hint="From"
        android:onClick="setTime2"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtTime2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".30"
        android:hint="To"
        android:onClick="setTime3"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtSet"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".40"
        android:hint="Description!!!"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"
        android:onClick="Save"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:minWidth="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

TimeTableDbHelper.java

```
    public class TimeTableDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String TABLE_NAMEM = "timetableM";
    public static final String COLUMN_NO1 = "c_no1";
    public static final String COLUMN_FROM_TIME1 = "FTIME1";
    public static final String COLUMN_TO_TIME1 = "TTIME1";
    public static final String COLUMN_DESC1 = "Description1";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "TimeTable.db";
    public TimeTableDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        final String SQL_CREATE_TIME_TABLE1 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAMEM + " (" +
                COLUMN_NO1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COLUMN_FROM_TIME1 + " STRING NOT NULL," +
                COLUMN_TO_TIME1 + " STRING NOT NULL," +
                COLUMN_DESC1 + " TEXT NOT NULL" +
                " );";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TIME_TABLE1);
    }     
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAMEM);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }   
    public void write1(int column_no, String ftime, String ttime, String desc) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_NO1, column_no);
        values.put(COLUMN_FROM_TIME1, ftime);
        values.put(COLUMN_TO_TIME1, ttime);
        values.put(COLUMN_DESC1, desc);
        Boolean res = CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot(TABLE_NAMEM, COLUMN_NO1, column_no);
        if (res == false) db.insert(TABLE_NAMEM, null, values);
        else db.update(TABLE_NAMEM, values, null, null);
        db.close();
    }    
    public int check(String tname) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String count = "SELECT count(*) FROM " + tname;
        Cursor mcursor = db.rawQuery(count, null);
        mcursor.moveToFirst();
        int icount = mcursor.getInt(0);
        return icount;
    }   
    public String rd1(int c_no, int col) {
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAMEM + " WHERE " + COLUMN_NO1 + " = " + c_no;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        String data = "";
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            // get  the  data into array,or class variable
            do {
                data = cursor.getString(col);
                //Log.i("TimeTableDbHelper", "Value read " + cursor.getString(6));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
        return data;
    }
    public boolean CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot(String TableName,
                                               String dbfield, int fieldValue) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String Query = "Select * from " + TableName + " where " + dbfield + " = " + fieldValue;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() <= 0) {
            cursor.close();
            return false;
        }
        cursor.close();
        return true;
    } 
}
```

Comment: `when user enters the save button twice` what a terrible user interface!

Comment: However, the problem is due to how you created your table. `the declared type of "STRING" has an affinity of NUMERIC, not TEXT.`, as reported in the [official SQLite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) - which you , apparently, didn't care to read.

Comment: Posting your code without the error message or exception message make it difficult for people to help you.

Comment: I just wanted to know how to update database with the existing code please help

Answer (score 0):

As stated here 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]):

> Returns:
>   the number of rows affected

So you can do just:

```
if (db.update(TABLE_NAMEM, values, null, null) == 0)
  db.insert(TABLE_NAMEM, null, values);

db.close();
```

Comment: What if the user tries to hit the save button after many inflated layouts?